# Add a semi colon to the previous line

Tags: python

I have a file like this note gap represent new lines.

```
Hello World )
    ;

Hello World ) ;

Hello World )
;
```

I have written a small python script to move the semicolon to the end of previous line

```
with open(path) as f:
    prev_line =''
    for current_line in f:
        matched = re.match('[^(.+)];',current_line,re.MULTILINE)
        if matched is not None:
            current_line = re.sub('[^(.+)];','',current_line,re.MULTILINE)
            prev_line = re.sub(r'^(.+)$',r'\1 ;',prev_line,re.MULTILINE)
        print prev_line.strip()
        prev_line = current_line.strip()
```

I am getting the expected out put except for the last line where the semicolon is missing

```
Hello World ) ;





Hello World ) ;



Hello World ) **semicolon is missing here**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using `\s*`:

```
>>> import re 
>>> s = '''Hello World )   
...         ;'''
>>> re.sub(r'\s*;', ';', s)
'Hello World );'
```

`\s*;` matches any amount of whitespace (including newlines) followed by a semicolon.

Also, `re.sub()` works on any number of instances of that pattern, so you could just do something like this:

```
with open(path) as f:
    fixed = re.sub(r'\s*;', ';', f.read())
```

Comment: The Hello World ) and the ; are on different lines so the space would not match i guess

Comment: Yes you are correct with the multtine regex i am able to get it right but the last semicolon is missing for some reason

Comment: Are you sure `re.MULTILINE` has anything to do with it?  Neither `^` nor `$` are being used here, and it looks to me like this would give the same answer without it.

Comment: @DSM: You're right. `re.MULTILINE` always confuses me. I've edited it out of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

if lines[-1].strip() == ';':
    lines.pop()
if lines[-1].strip()[-1] != ';'
    lines[-1] = lines[-1].rstrip() + ';'

with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(lines))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If the semicolon is always on its own line, you should be able to just find it by iterating through the file after which you can add it to the end of the previous line, like so:

```
file = open(path, 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
  if ';' in line:
    lines[lines.index(line)-1] += line
    lines.remove(line)
```

footnote: wasn't really sure if you wanted to keep the spaces in front of ';'. I just put together the simplest possible solution.